# aLogcat not displaying stack traces of android app on samsung galaxy

Tags: android, debugging, logcat, android-logcat, android-debug

I have put log messages in my android app and created APK file.
I have then installed my android app on Samsung galaxy device.
I have also installed aLogcat.
when I run my app on Samsung and go to aLogcat, it is not displaying log messages.i have checked the filter and setting in aLogcat.
it is set to 'verbose"

can any expert  help me here please

```
        Log.i(TAG,"entering onCreate");
```

Answer (score 0):

To display logs of other applications alogcat must have root/super user permissions. So grant alogcat root permissions and read the logs

Comment: when I execute below command in Terminal Emulator app on Samsung phone I am getting device not found

Comment: adb shell pm grant <pkg> android.permission.READ_LOGS. I tried to connect phone to laptop.but when I execute adb devices command in command prompt  (adk install.../../adb )it says list of devices but no devices displayed.